# Crear listas permutadas en Python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa en Python para generar diccionarios dada una palabra.

Pongamos por ejemplo que actualmente tengo 3 funciones.

```
def addYear(palabra): #Añade un año a la palabra
def addSpecialChar(palabra): #Añade el caracter especial ! a la palabra
def toNumber(palabra): #Cambia las vocales por numeros
```

Si introduzco la palabra `ejemplo` se deberia generar el diccionario

```
ejemplo 
ejemplo!
ejemplo!2019
ejemplo2019
ejemplo2019!
3j3mpl0
3j3mpl0!
3j3mpl0!2019
3j3mpl02019
3j3mpl02019!
```

Como deberia de hacer la llamada a las funciones para que se den todas las permutaciones posibles?

Actualmente lo que hago es anidar funciones como por ejemplo:

```
addYear(addSpecialChar(toNumber(palabra)))
```

De tal modo que:

Al salir de la funcion toNumber mi lista tendría las palabras `ejemplo, 3j3mpl0`

Al salir de la funcion addSpecialChar mi lista tendría las palabras `ejemplo, 3j3mpl0,ejemplo!, 3j3mpl0!`

Al salir de la funcion addSpecialChar mi lista tendría las palabras `ejemplo, 3j3mpl0, ejemplo!, 3j3mpl0!, ejemplo2019, 3j3mpl02019, ejemplo!2019, 3j3mpl0!2019`

Pero esta solucion no tiene en cuenta todas las posibles combinaciones, por ejemplo, no generaria la combinacion `ejemplo2019!` ni `3j3mpl02019!`

Answer (score 1):

Haz uso de la libreria `itertools`. Supongamos que mis métodos son estos:

```
 def add1(a):
    b = []
    for i in a:
        i+="1"
        b.append(i)
    return b

def add2(a):
    b = []
    for i in a:
        i+="2"
        b.append(i)
    return b

def add3(a):
    b = []
    for i in a:
        i+="3"
        b.append(i)
    return b
```

Entonces defino una lista con estos métodos (por lo que si en el futuro quieres, puedes añadir nuevos métodos y seguirá funcionando):

```
methods = [add1, add2, add3]
levels = len(methods)
lista =  ["a"]
```

Ahora generamos todas las permutaciones posibles:

```
all_permutations = []
for level in range(1,levels+1):
    print(level)
    all_permutations = all_permutations + list(itertools.permutations(methods, level))
```

Y finalmente recorremos las palabras y las permutaciones que hemos calculado:

```
output = []
for word in lista:
    for permuta in all_permutations:
        temp_word = word
        for p in permuta:
            temp_word = p(temp_word)
        output = output + temp_word
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
['a1',
 'a2',
 'a3',
 'a12',
 'a13',
 'a21',
 'a23',
 'a31',
 'a32',
 'a123',
 'a132',
 'a213',
 'a231',
 'a312',
 'a321']
```

Answer (score 1):

Me gustaría mejorar la respuesta de @sergiomahi.

La idea es tener una lista de funciones a aplicar e ir haciendo *combinaciones* con ella. Para ello necesitamos dos cosas:

- un modo de combinar las funciones:

```py
def compose(fs, x):
    res = x
    for f in fs:
        res = f(res)
    return res
```

- un modo de obtener todas las combinaciones

```py
from itertools import permutations

def all_permutations(lst):
    return [x for i in range(len(lst)) for x in permutations(lst, i + 1)]
```

A las funciones que tenemos hay que añadir la *identidad* para tener todos los casos posibles. Esta función la podemos definir como:

```py
def identity(x):
    return x
```

Combinando todo, tenemos:

````py
word = "Ejemplo"
fs = [identity, addYear, addSpecialChar, toNumber]
resultado = [compose(fs, word) for fs in all_permutations(trans)]

El problema es que alguna funciones son _conmutativas_ y otras no. Por ejemplo, `toNumber` da igual en qué orden se ejecute, pero no `addSpecialChar`. Por este motivo, en la lista de resultados se obtienen algunas repeticiones. Para eliminarlas basta con obtener un conjunto (set) en lugar de lista.

Todo junto:

```python
from itertools import permutations


def identity(palabra):
    return palabra


def addYear(palabra):  # Añade un año a la palabra
    return palabra + "2019"


def addSpecialChar(palabra):  # Añade el caracter especial ! a la palabra
    return palabra + "!"


def toNumber(palabra):  # Cambia las vocales por numeros
    d = {
        "a": "4",
        "e": "3",
        "i": "1",
        "o": "0",
        "A": "4",
        "E": "3",
        "I": "1",
        "O": "0",
    }
    return "".join(d.get(c, c) for c in palabra)


def compose(fs, x):
    res = x
    for f in fs:
        res = f(res)
    return res


def all_permutations(lst):
    return [x for i in range(len(lst)) for x in permutations(lst, i + 1)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "Ejemplo"
    trans = [identity, addYear, addSpecialChar, toNumber]
    res = {compose(fs, word) for fs in all_permutations(trans)}
    print(res)
````

---

**Edición**

He caído en la cuenta de que tal como está definido `compose` no es necesaria la función `identity`. `compose([])` equivaldría a `identy()`, con lo que se puede simplificar el código de este modo:

```py
from itertools import permutations


def addYear(palabra):  # Añade un año a la palabra
    return palabra + "2019"


def addSpecialChar(palabra):  # Añade el caracter especial ! a la palabra
    return palabra + "!"


def toNumber(palabra):  # Cambia las vocales por numeros
    d = {
        "a": "4",
        "e": "3",
        "i": "1",
        "o": "0",
    }
    return "".join(d.get(c.lower(), c) for c in palabra)


def compose(fs, x):
    res = x
    for f in fs:
        res = f(res)
    return res


def all_permutations(lst):
    return [x for i in range(len(lst) + 1) for x in permutations(lst, i)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "Ejemplo"
    trans = [addYear, addSpecialChar, toNumber]
    res = {compose(fs, word) for fs in all_permutations(trans)}
    print(res)
```